# how to display other field also in aggregate in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

below is my code. i want to find all the rows that satisfy the condition that is in the aggregate method. As aggregate returns me the array of object i want to find rows that match this condition. and i want the data in sorted order. i have to use sort method of mongodb not of node js.

```
train.aggregate([
        {$group :
            _id :'$trainNo',    
            total : {$max : '$distance' }
            trainName : {'$first' : '$trainName'}
        }
        ]).sort({total : 1}).forEach(function(docs) {
                // train.find( {'distance' : docs.total, 'trainNo' : docs._id}, {trainNo : 1, trainName : 1, distance : 1}).toArray(function (err,data) {
                //  finalResult.push(data);
                // })
        console.log(docs);
        });
```

Comment: Can you please provide the example documents and expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the **[`$max`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/#grp._S_max)** operator in your **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** step, use **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)**  operator so that you can extend your aggregation **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline step with the fields you want to return. This works best when you have your initial pipeline documents sorted before the grouping stage.

The final **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** pipeline stage will serve to order your resulting documents. The following shows how you can go about this:

---

```
var pipeline = [
    { "$sort": { "distance": -1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$trainNo",
            "total": { "$first": "$distance" },
            "trainName": { "$first": "$trainName" },
            "distance": { "$first": "$distance" },
            "id": { "$first": "$_id" }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": "$id",
            "trainNo": "$_id",
            "total": 1,
            "trainName": 1,
            "distance": 1
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "total": -1 } }
]

train.aggregate(pipeline, function(err, r){
    console.log(r);
})
```

---

In the above pipeline, the first step is the **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** operator which is similar to SQL's `ORDER BY` clause. To sort a particular field in descending order specify -1 and specify 1 if that field has to be sorted in ascending order.
In your case it's sorting against the `distance` field descending. This is a necessary operation for the next pipeline stage, the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** step where you need to get the maximum `distance` for each grouped documents by getting the value from the first/top document when the grouped documents are ordered.

One thing to note here is when executing a pipeline, MongoDB pipes operators into each other. "Pipe" here takes the Linux meaning: the output of an operator becomes the input of the following operator. The result of each operator is a new collection of documents. So Mongo executes the previous pipeline as follows:

```
collection | $sort | $group | $project | $sort => result
```

Inside the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline, you are now grouping the ordered documents by the `trainNo` field and then using the accumulators to return the desired aggregation on the grouped documents. The accumulator operator **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** is ideal in this grouping operation because it returns a value from the first document for each group when the documents are in a defined order, in this case you have them ordered by distance descending.

Accumulators used in the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** stage maintain their state (e.g. totals, maximums, minimums, and related data) as documents progress through the pipeline.

To get the documents with the desired field, the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** operator which is similar to `SELECT` in SQL is used to rename the field names and select/deselect the fields to be returned, out of the grouped fields. If you specify 0 for a field, it will NOT be sent in the pipeline to the next operator.

The final **[`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#pipe._S_sort)** pipeline step then re-orders the documents on the desired key.